# Elegant way of returning from haskell function?

Tags: haskell

Hi I am new to haskell.

I want to return something like

```
return ((myfunc list1) ++ list2 )
```

here list1 and list2 are two lists and myfunc also returns a list

What would me most elegant way of doing this.Should I use $ operator ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks to me you can replace it to `return $ myfunc list1 ++ list2`. But are you sure you need a `return` function to begin with?

Comment: I would probably write this as `return $ myfunc list1 ++ list2` or `return (myfunc list1 ++ list2)`.  However, if this question is just about code style then stackoverflow really isn't the place for these types of questions since it's subjective.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about code style, not a technical problem.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem  This is only a return statement of original function

Comment: Mind that `return` is not really a statement. It is a function. Personally I think `return` was perhaps not a good name since it create confusion compared to returning in imperative languages.

Comment: Oh, Noob to Haskell :)

Comment: Haskell doesn't have "statements" in the way that imperative languages have. You write the return value of a function by putting things on the right-hand side of an `=` sign.

Comment: We can mitigate the problem posed by the name "return" socially by discouraging `return` and instead use `pure`.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it like this:

```
foo list1 list2 = myfunc list1 ++ list2
```

If you actually need `return` (which I suspect you don't), then using `$` might be warranted; but the explicitly parenthesized version is perfectly fine, too:

```
foo list1 list2 = return (myfunc list1 ++ list2)
foo list1 list2 = return $ myfunc list1 ++ list2
```